# Typescript Array.isArray guard statement and return types on function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the following function that works as expected, if you pass an array into the second parameter the return type is correctly typed as an array of the generic T.

```
type V<M, T> = { new (model: M): T };
interface GenericBuilder {
  <M = any, T = any>(View: V<M, T>, m: M): T;
  <M = any, T = any>(View: V<M, T>, m: M[]): Array<T>;
  <M = any, T = any>(View: V<M, T>, m: M | Array<M>): T | T[];
}

export const builder: GenericBuilder = <M = any, T = any>(
  View: ViewClass<M, T>,
  m: M | Array<M>
) => (Array.isArray(m) ? m.map((l) => new View(l)) : new View(m));


const model = { x: 2 };
class MyView {
   model: any;
   constructor(model) { this.model = model }
   get y() { 
     return this.model.x * 2;
   }
};
const result = builder(V, model);
assert(result.y == 2); // passes tsc
const list = builder(V, [model]);
assert(list.map(r => r.y) == [2]); // passes tsc
```

As soon as i try and introduce a wrapper function around the class using the builder function typing falls back to the implementation of T | T[] rather than the overrides provided in the interface.

```
export function view<M = any, T = any>(View: V<M,T>, T>) {
  return {
    build: (m: M | M[]) => builder(View, m),
  };
}
const Wrapped = view(MyView)
Wrapped.build(model).y // fails tsc
Wrapped.build([model]).map(r => r.y) // fails tsc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export function view<M = any, T = any>(View: V<M,T>) {
  return {
    build: (m: M | M[]) => builder(View, m),
  };
}
```

Your `view` wrapper has a property `build` which takes an argument `M | M[]`.  The inferred return type is `T | T[]`.  The import thing to note here is that `build` only has **one** call signature.  You are expecting Typescript to know that calling `build(M)` and `build(M[])` are different, but you haven't told it that.

There might be a cleaner way to do this, but you can definitely achieve what you want by overloading the `build` function.

```
export function view<M = any, T = any>(View: V<M, T>) {

  function build(m: M): T;
  function build(m: M[]): T[];
  function build(m: M| M[]): T | T[];
  function build(m: M| M[]): T | T[] {
    return builder(View, m);
  }
  
  return {
    build
  };
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nd3vvw)